# converting JSON to a Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

looking for some guidance, Have to convert a json that looks like this:

```
d = {
'dbname' : {
    'table1' : [
        {
            'Name': 'wow',
            'Type': 'str'   
        }, 
        {
            'Name': 'beto',
            'Type': 'int'  
        },
        {
            'Name': 'claro',
            'Type': 'int'    
        }
        ],
    'table2' : [
        {
            'Name': 'date',
            'Type': 'str'   
        }, 
        {
            'Name': 'clear',
            'Type': 'bool'        
        }
        ]
    
},
'dbname2' : {
    'table3' : [
        {
            'Name': 'wow',
            'Type': 'str'
            
        }
        ] 
}
```

}

into a dataframe that resembles something like this:

[image: dataframe]

so far i'm able to produce a dataframe with just 'dbname' using the following:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(d,
meta='dbname',
meta_prefix='Parent',
record_path=['dbname', 'table1' ])
df = df.explode('Parentdbname')
df.rename(columns={'Parentdbname':'TableName'}, inplace=True)
```

outputs:

```
    Name Type TableName
0    wow  str    table1
0    wow  str    table2
1   beto  int    table1
1   beto  int    table2
2  claro  int    table1
2  claro  int    table2
```

but cant seem to get get dbname2 (or further 'dbname's as the json file is longer) into the dataframe(tried creating a list of the keys for the meta and record path) , i'd ideally like to include the column for the dbname in this too but as the table names in the actual json file are all prefixed with their corresponding db it is not relevant.

EDIT: realised the dataframe output is incorrect in the first place, just repeats the values for table1

Comment: You need to iterate through the entries and merge or append each additional data frame.  Instructions for that are available from any PANDAS tutorial.

Comment: @Prune added a nested loop but get back key errors:

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
"I did some stuff and got errors" is not a problem specification; there's no way we can correct code you didn't post, to get rid of errors you didn't include.

Comment: @Prune sorry i posted prematurely without finishing:
`for dbkey, tblkey in d.items(): 
     for tbl in tblkey.keys():
         df = pd.json_normalize(d,
         meta=[dbkey, tbl],
         meta_prefix='Parent',
         record_path=[dbkey, tbl])
         pandalist.append(df)
glue = pd.concat(pandalist)
df = df.explode('Parentdbname')
df.rename(columns={'Parentdbname':'TableName'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: Please edit the updates into the question; as you can see, comments are not sufficient for posting code.

Answer (score 0):

```
## You can use a for loop here if you have many tables.
dbname = pd.DataFrame(d['dbname']['table1'])
dbname['table'] = 'table1'

dbname3 = pd.DataFrame(d['dbname']['table2'])
dbname3['table'] = 'table2'

dbname2 = pd.DataFrame(d['dbname2']['table3'])
dbname2['table'] = 'table3'

pd.concat([dbname2, dbname, dbname3])
```

Output:

```
    Name    Type    table
0   wow     str     table3
0   wow     str     table1
1   beto    int     table1
2   claro   int     table1
0   date    str     table2
1   clear   bool    table2
```